How to filter results by the presence of an optional field in Prisma with MongoDB?
I am using Prisma with MongoDB, and I have a model where one of the fields, deletedAt, is optional. This field is used for soft deletion, meaning if deletedAt is present, the record is considered deleted. I want to filter out the results to only include records where deletedAt is either null or does not exist at all.
Here is my model definition:
model CommentProject {
  id        String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  content   String
  deletedAt DateTime? 
  modified  Boolean   @default(false)
  createdAt DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime  @updatedAt
  project   Project   @relation(fields: [projectId], references: [id])
  projectId String    @db.ObjectId
  author    User      @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  authorId  String    @db.ObjectId
}

I tried filtering with the following query, but it doesn't work as expected:
const comments = await prisma.commentProject.findMany({
  where: {
    projectId: input.projectId,
    deletedAt: null, // This does not return results where `deletedAt` is undefined
  },
});

I need a way to filter the results to only include comments where deletedAt is either null or does not exist. However, Prisma does not seem to support the MongoDB $exists operator directly, which would be the typical way to handle this in MongoDB.
What is the best way to achieve this with Prisma and MongoDB without using workarounds like default values or additional fields? I am also not looking for a solution that involves using raw queries.
I found this same issue still open:
https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/17137
thanks

Since MongoDB query operators are type-sensitive, you might try with $not and $gte and a very old datetime (like epoch)

Thanks Joe, I wanted to avoid workaround because otherwise, I could just use a required boolean field like isDeleted along with deleteAt optional. I was hoping for a clean solution from Prisma since MongoDB offers an operator called $exists to check if a field exists or not
